# ES6 module scope

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I have the code:

```
// lib.js
var a = "a";
export var b = "b";

// main.js
console.log(a); // "a" variable is not available in a global scope
import {b} from "lib";
console.log(a); // is "a" variable available in a global scope or only in a module scope?
```

Can I use "a" variable in a global scope after module importing or is it available only in a module scope? Will ES6 modules have a similar working principle like this trick:

```
// module    
exports.module1 = (function(){ var a = "a"; })(); // "a" variable is not available in a global scope
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Can I use "a" variable in a global scope after module importing or is it available only in a module scope?

It's only available inside the module it was declared in.

> Will ES6 modules have a similar working principle like this trick: [...]

Basically yes.

---

ES6 has these kinds of scopes, order from "top" to "bottom":

- Global scope
- Module scope
- Function scope
- Block scope

Comment: [Good explanation about modules (by Lin Clark @linclark)](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/)

Comment: excellent answer @Felix Kling +1, so when we import some functionality it only lives in the "global scope top-level" of that file that imported that other functionality, right?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, it lives in module scope.

Answer (score 6):

You can do `globalThis.a = "a"` and access it after that module has loaded. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis

Answer (score 0):

lets say you are exporting something to another module. example you are exporting `var b = 'b'`, but you are not exporting the `var a = 'a'`. this means you are only able to use `var a = 'a'` in `lib.js`, It is local to the module it was declared in and only can be used in that module. `var a` is scoped to the `lib.js` module.