# What's the point of adding property to window?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm learning client-side javascript and i noticed in some tutorials let's say we are making a game, even with webpack bundler in place, they still do:

```
// game.js
function Game() {
  // ... some code
}

module.exports = Game;

// index.js

const Game = require("./game.js");
window.Game = Game;
```

What's the point of adding such constructor function to window? we can always require them wherever we use it and use webpack to bundle them right?

Comment: Attaching properties to window object is not a good approach. Consider not to listen those tutors who suggest to do like this.

Comment: @uamanager thx, do you have suggestion on avoiding circular dependency without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorials do that, because ES6 module scripts have an own ("closed") scope of variables, which doesn't allow to play around with its objects outside of it. See question [ES6 module scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287977/es6-module-scope) for more about this topic.

With `window.Game = Game;` the `Game` instance becomes accessible everywhere, which can ne good for debugging over [the browser console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console), but you shoudn't do this in a deployed software build.

Comment: thx. i went further on the project and realized they did this because otherwise it's very easy to have a circular dependency when A requires B, B requires C, while C just need a constant from A. i'll dig a bit how we usually solve that in production