# Functions not working when ```type="module"``` or import

Tags: javascript, function, import

```
import testBtn from '/functions.js'


window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('questions1').style.display = 'block'
    document.getElementById('questions2').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('questions3').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('questions4').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('questions5').style.display = 'none'
}

function nextQuestion() {
testBtn("hello")
}
```

all functions do not work when i try to import or when i change the script type to `type="module"` the function works when all of there are no imports or change in script type, and i receive the following error - `Uncaught ReferenceError: nextQuestion is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 module scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287977/es6-module-scope)

Comment: no sorry, i am having trouble trying to implement this. i have tried to load the javascript module into the actual button input and try to see if the src="js file" would work but i havent had any luck. all i'm trying to do is import the variables from that javascript variable as the variables will have values from teh answered questions off the previous questions. so all i need to is liteally import that variable into the next html page and display the calculation

Answer (score 9):

ECMAScript modules do not use the global scope, so an `onclick="nextQuestion"` attribute on an HTML element will not be able to find `nextQuestion` since it is not in the global scope, but in module scope (when used with `type="module"`). To fix this, put the `nextQuestion` function into the global scope:

```js
window.nextQuestion = function() {
  testBtn("hello")
}
```