# Uncaught ReferenceError: candle1 is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1 (anonymous) @ VM12033:1

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why I am able to console.log candle1, but I cannot type it directly into the console without an error.

Here is the Candle.js code:

```
class Candle {
  constructor(scent, material, color, numWicks, waxColor) {
    this.scent = scent;
    this.container = {
      material: material,
      color: color,
      numWicks: numWicks,
    };
    this.waxColor = waxColor;
  }
  newNumWicks(numWicks) {
    this.container.numWicks = numWicks;
  }
  newMaterial(material) {
    this.container.material = material;
  }
  newScent(scent) {
    this.scent = scent;
  }
  newColor(color) {
    this.container.color = color;
  }
  newWaxColor(waxColor) {
    this.waxColor = waxColor;
  }
}

export default Candle;
```

Here is the script.js code:

```
import Candle from "./Candle.js";

const candle1 = new Candle(
    "Midnight Blue Citrus", 
    "Glass", 
    "Blue", 
    3, 
    "White");

console.log(candle1);

console.log(candle1.container.material);
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Practice: Making classes and objects</title>
    <script type="module" src="Candle.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Backpack.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

This is the result of running the code:
[console.log results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUzfN.jpg)

The red error message is me trying to type candle1 directly into the console.

Please ignore the two yellow messages, they are due to a couple of extensions that I use.

Comment: Because the `console.log(candle1);` is in the same scope (module's scope).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 module scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287977/es6-module-scope)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an issue with ES6 modules and their variables being access limited to the script (CS term: [scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science))).

You can make the make `candle1` accessible everywhere by adding `window.candle1 = candle1` to the bottom of the script. [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) being the global scope in this case.

> The `window` interface is home to a variety of functions, namespaces, objects, and constructors which are not necessarily directly associated with the concept of a user interface window. However, the `window` interface is a suitable place to include these items that need to be globally available. (...)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58594093/7638119) for more information about this problem.

Comment: So, even though candle1 was declared in script.js, it's not globally scoped because it is importing from a class in Candle.js. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: @potstickerNut Yes. The variable is declared inside the module and therefore is only accessable there. This is different from scripts that are not embedded with `type="module"`. Variables of regular/old (non-module) scripts' are globally accessible. This confuses many people (me once as well). Your not alone

Comment: This is why I am able to console.log it, but cannot type it directly into the console? I apologize if my questions are basic, but I am still in the early stages of learning.

Comment: @potstickerNut No need to apologize. Some friendly advice, since you're new here: It's okay to ask seemingly silly questions on StackOverflow (tho this is controversial). The things that are mainly important here are: 1. Make it clear that you tried to help yourself and asking is your last resort. 2. Narrow the problem down as good as you can and don't just dump your code and error here. 3. Strictly adhere to the ["How do I ask?" Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

You are using [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Every module has its own [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). So, the object `candle1` is only available inside the module it was declared in, not globally.
Thus, the `console.log` in the js file works since it's in the same scope, but doesn't work on dev tools because that is the global scope.

---

ES6 has these kinds of scopes (top to bottom):

- Global scope
- Module scope
- Function scope
- Block scope

---

If you want to access something globally, you can create a [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object).
Example: `window.candle1 = candle1;`

Comment: Why am I able to console.log it? Shouldn't the console.log also throw an error?

Comment: Please do not answer common and frequently asked questions. Instead of linking or quoting a duplicate answer, just flag it. It helps our system to stay clean. Flags on Stack Overflow are not meant to punish people, they are educational and will not subtract reputation from them (except spam flags or abusive flags). If you still wanna answer to gain some reputation, do it, but keep in mind: Authors will probably delete their answer with many down votes to get their reputation back and that will also apply to you too, but negatively. You encourage people to not research their problems themselves

Comment: @NiklasE. This is a DIRECT answer to the question in topic !! It is not an answer to "what is module scope". It's an answer to "why the error" !!

Comment: @Ergis But it's the exact same (induced) problem with the exact same solution as [this answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58594093/7638119).